# Symfony2 Doctrine DBAL Query Builder with MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm, dbal

I have to work with a real legacy mssql database and I'm trying to use the Doctrine DBAL Query Builder.

FYI I'm on a linux machine with working freetds connection

Until now I tried the https://github.com/realestateconz/MssqlBundle

and configured the database connection like this

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:     default
        connections:
            default:
                driver_class:   Realestate\MssqlBundle\Driver\PDODblib\Driver
                host:           %database_host%
                dbname:         %database_name%
                user:           %database_user%
                password:       %database_password%
```

Now I used in the controller

```
    $conn = $this->get('database_connection');
```

But now when I write `$qb = $conn->createQueryBuilder();`

it isn't aware of the createQueryBuilder...

Anyone knows a solution?

Comment: Have you tried `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("<your-...>")->createQueryBuilder()`?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?